# Integrate Landoop Docker image with another docker image

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

I am trying to run 2 docker containers. One is Landoop's Kafka container which exposes couple of ports to local host and One kafka connect container which tries to access the ports exposed by the other image. I am able to access the ports exposed by Landoop's Kafka container but having issues trying to access the ports from the other container.

PS: I am using MAC and I tried launching my other container using `--network="host"`.

```
docker run -it --network="host" --env-file env-file.sh --name NAME IMAGE
```

But the container gets killed as soon as I launch it . I am using

`docker run --rm -it -p 2181:2181 -p 3030:3030 -p 8081:8081 -p 8082:8082 -p 8083:8083 -p 9092:9092 -h 127.0.0.1 -e ADV_HOST=127.0.0.1 landoop/fast-data-dev` to launch Landoop docker.

Comment: https://github.com/Landoop/kafka-connectors-tests

We are using the `fast-data-dev` and compose multiple dockers together i.e. `fast-data-dev` + `elastic-search` 
in order to do integration tests on the `stream-reactor` collection of kafka connectors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/#the-default-bridge-network) you can find the following information:

> Containers connected to the default bridge network can communicate with each other by IP address. Docker does not support automatic service discovery on the default bridge network. If you want containers to be able to resolve IP addresses by container name, you should use user-defined networks instead. You can link two containers together using the legacy docker run --link option, but this is not recommended in most cases.

While your attempt at using the `host` network and directing yourself at `127.0.0.1` *almost* makes sense; normally that address is assigned to the loopback interface, so rather than using than being able to access other ports on your machine - instead it never leaves the Docker container.

If you're not using a [Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/) file - which would normally bring all services up in a default overlay network, and instead would like to run everything by hand via `docker container run` commands - your setup should look something like this:

```
docker network create your_new_network

docker container run -d --network your_new_network --name a_container_1 your_image

docker container run -d --network your_new_network --name another_container
```

Now - from within those containers, you would be able to address each one as `a_container_1` and `another_container` respectfully.

Your container stopping may or may not be related; unfortunately I can't answer that with the information given - but this should give you enough information to connect your containers. Cheers!

Comment: Correct me if i am wrong .
 docker run --rm -it --network my_network --env-file kafka-connect-env.sh --name IMAGE NAMES
and 
docker run --rm -it --network my_network  -p 2181:2181 -p 3030:3030 -p 8081:8081 -p 8082:8082 -p 8083:8083 -p 9092:9092 -e ADV_HOST=127.0.0.1 landoop/fast-data-dev

And I am trying to access :
BOOTSTRAP_URL=localhost:9092
Schema Registry  URL=http://localhost:8081
(From the 1st container)

Am I missing something? Bcoz the container gets killed immediately

Comment: I tried using localhost,docker.for.mac.localhost. Actual IP of the other landoop container. Also when I run docker inspect , both of them seems to be on the same network.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think this variable is an issue > ADV_HOST=127.0.0.1
When you want to connect to the Kafka (running in your docker container)from your host machine this variable helps that connection 
However, if you define that variable it confuses the other container from seeing Kafka container.
2 thing to try:
1. replace 127.0.0.1 with the local IP address if the network is HOST  i.e --network="host" and -e ADV_HOST=[local_ip]
2. remove that ADV_HOST advertise host address and use the approach @tj-biddle mentioned